# Sending Array of Json objects in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I want to send an array of JSON objects in a put request body.

JSON body:

```
[
 {
    "a":1,
    "b":2
 },
 {
    "a":2,
    "b":1
 }
]
```

I am using HTTP::put to make the request. I send data in the Json as a hash.

`put("url", data: json)`

But, this causes problems as on the client side it is decoded as :

```
[
 "data":[{
    "a":1,
    "b":2
 },
 {
    "a":2,
    "b":1
 }]
]
```

How do I send the Json without hashing or is there any way to get the values out of the hash before sending??

Comment: are you sure? because response `json` is not a valid json you wrote

Comment: If you mean the quotes around data, I have added it. It was a typo

Comment: I believe in client-side parsed `json` is look like this: https://gist.github.com/mur-wtag/c2fde2f21c2fa33c424b6b68371c804c

Comment: `put("url", json)` should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We couldn't use HTTP::Put.new because of some parameters that were set internally. We solved it by adding a method in the Her library that in turn uses Faraday to make the request. I am posting the method used here.

```
      response = self.use_api.connection.put do |req|
        req.url url
        req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        req.body = json
      end
```

I am not sure if this is the best method or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `Content-Type`:

```
json_data = '[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":1 }]'
hash_body = JSON.parse json_data
uri = URI.parse('https://www.google.com/api/something')

request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.request_uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
request.body = hash_body
response = http.request(request)
```

Cheers!